# Java number guessing game, while-loop

Tags: java

I am making a guessing game which makes a random number between 1 and 200. Whenever I guess, the program will tell me if its too high or too low, then ask me to try again.

I'm supposed to put a "try again" input box inside my code. Now my code is only showing "your guess is too high/too low". I don't understand where and how to put it.

This is my code:

```java
import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.*;

class Tallspill {

    public int nyttTall() {
        int tilfeldig = (int) (Math.random() * 201);
        return tilfeldig;
    }

    public void visMelding(String melding) {
        showMessageDialog(null,melding);
    }

    private void forLite(int tall) {
        if (tall < nyttTall()) {
            String melding = (tall + " er for lite. Prøv igjen!");
            visMelding(melding);
        }
    }

    private void forStort(int tall) {
        if (tall>nyttTall()) {
            String melding = (tall+" er for stort. Prøv igjen!");
            visMelding(melding);
        }
    }

    public void avsluttRunde(int antall, int tall) {
        String melding = (tall + "er riktig. Du brukte " + antall + " forsøk.");
        visMelding(melding);
    }

    public void kjørspill() {
        int random = nyttTall();
        int tall = Integer.parseInt(showInputDialog("Skriv inn et tall mellom 0 og 200"));
        int antall = 0;

        while(tall != random) {
            if (tall < random) {
                forLite(tall);
                //metode for nytt forsøk
            }
            antall++;
            if (tall > random) {
                forStort(tall);
                //metode for nytt forsøk
            }
            antall++;

            if (tall == random) {
                avsluttRunde(antall,tall);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tallspill spill = new Tallspill();
        spill.kjørspill();
    }
}
```

I tried putting an input string inside the while-loop, but then it just looped on "try again". I also tried putting it inside the `toolow` and `toohigh` methods, but then I got an error.

Comment: `int tall = Integer.parseInt(showInputDialog("Skriv inn et tall mellom 0 og 200"));` has to go inside your `while` loop

Comment: Following @LinFelix comment, `tall` varialbe is not being updated, that's why it's staying the the while loop for ever

Comment: Increment only once **inside and at the beginning** of your `while` loop.

Comment: i tried to update my program to english. sorry about that. thanks, i will try that!

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your solution.
After number is big or small you do not show the number input dialog again. Because that code is outside your while loop

```
int tall = Integer.parseInt(showInputDialog("Skriv inn et tall mellom 0 og 200"));
```

I have refactored your code a bit.

```
public void kjørspill() {
        int random = nyttTall();
        int tall = Integer.parseInt(showInputDialog("Skriv inn et tall mellom 0 og 200"));
        int antall = 0;

        while(tall != random) {
            antall++;
            if (tall < random) {
                forLite(tall);
                tall = Integer.parseInt(showInputDialog("Skriv inn et tall mellom 0 og 200"));
                //metode for nytt forsøk
            } else if (tall > random) {
                forStort(tall);
                tall = Integer.parseInt(showInputDialog("Skriv inn et tall mellom 0 og 200"));
                //metode for nytt forsøk
            }
        }
        avsluttRunde(antall,tall);
    }
```

Comment: now it makes sense. thank you so much. the only problem now is that the avsluttRunde method (when i guess right) isnt showing

Comment: @Hannne you are right. need to take that condition out of the loop. because when tall == random the loop does not run. I have updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Ask user inside infinite while block and exit if user canceled or guessed the number. Check if input number is correct. Remove over checking from Tallspill class methods.

```
import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog;
import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog;

class Tallspill {

    public int nyttTall() {
        int tilfeldig = (int) (Math.random() * 201);
        return tilfeldig;
    }

    public void visMelding(String melding) {
        showMessageDialog(null, melding);
    }

    private void forLite(int tall) {
        String melding = tall + " er for lite. Prøv igjen!";
        visMelding(melding);
    }

    private void forStort(int tall) {
        String melding = tall + " er for stort. Prøv igjen!";
        visMelding(melding);
    }

    public void avsluttRunde(int antall, int tall) {
        String melding = tall + "er riktig. Du brukte " + antall + " forsøk.";
        visMelding(melding);
    }

    public void invalidNumber() {
        String melding = "Invalid number. Try again.";
        visMelding(melding);
    }

    public void kjrspill() {
        int random = nyttTall();
        int tall;
        int antall = 0;

        while (true) {
            antall++;
            String tallStr = showInputDialog("Skriv inn et tall mellom 0 og 200");
            if (tallStr == null)
                return;

            try {
                tall = Integer.parseInt(tallStr);

                if (tall < random)
                    forLite(tall); //metode for nytt forsøk

                if (tall > random)
                    forStort(tall); //metode for nytt forsøk

                if (tall == random){
                    avsluttRunde(antall, tall);
                    return;
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                invalidNumber();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class TestGuessNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tallspill spill = new Tallspill();
        spill.kjrspill();
    }
}
```

Comment: i will put try/catch as well. thanks alot!

Comment: @Hannne you can thank also by voting :)

Answer (score 0):

In your **Numbergame** class, the `tooSmall()` and `tooBig()` methods are always comparing against a new random number. The random number should be a class member variable that gets filled by the `newNumber()` method, for example:

```
public class Numbergame {

    int randomNumber;
      
    public int newNumber() {
        this.randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 201);
        return randomNumber;
    }

    private void tooSmall(int number) {
        if (number < randomNumber) {
            String message = (number + " is too low. Try again!");
            showMessage(message);
        }
    }

    private void tooBig(int number) {
        if (number > randomNumber) {
            String message = (number + " is too high. Try again!");
            showMessage(message);
        }
    }

    // rest of class code ...
```

Here is the entire class reworked. I have also added some input validation so to perhaps eliminate at least some obvious exceptions:

```
public class Numbergame {

    int randomNumber;
    
    public int newNumber() {
        this.randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 201);
        return randomNumber;

    }

    public void showMessage(String message) {
        showMessageDialog(message);

    }

    private void tooSmall(int number) {
        if (number < randomNumber) {
            String message = (number + " is too low. Try again!");
            showMessage(message);
        }
    }

    private void showMessageDialog(String message) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message, "Just so you know...", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
    
    private String showInputDialog(String message) {
        return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, message, "User Input...", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    }
    
    private void tooBig(int number) {
        if (number > randomNumber) {
            String message = (number + " is too high. Try again!");
            showMessage(message);
        }
    }

    public void endRound(int tries, int number) {
        String message = (number + " is CORRECT!. You used " + tries + " tries.");
        showMessage(message);
    }

    public void playgame() {
        int random = newNumber();
        int tries = 0;
        
        int number = -1;
        while (number != random) {
            tries++;
            String userVal = "";
            while (userVal.isEmpty()) {
                userVal = showInputDialog("<html>Enter a number between "
                            + "<font size='4' color=blue>0</font> and <font size='4' "
                            + "color=blue>200</font>:<br><center><font color=gray>('q' "
                            + "to quit)</font></center><br></html>");
                if (userVal == null || userVal.isEmpty()) { 
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "<html>You must enter <font size='4'>"
                                        + "<b>something!</b></font></html>", 
                                        "Invalid Entry!", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    userVal = "";
                }
                else if (userVal.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
                    if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure you want to Quit?", 
                                          "Quit Application?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == 0){
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                    else {
                        userVal = "";
                    }
                }
                else if (userVal.matches("\\d+")) {
                    number = Integer.parseInt(userVal);
                    if (number < 0 || number > 200) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Entry! (" 
                                + number + ")Try again...", "Invalid Entry!", 
                                JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                        userVal = "";
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if (number < random) {
                tooSmall(number);
            }
            else if (number > random) {
                tooBig(number);
            }
            else if (number == random) {
                endRound(tries, number);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And of course....to play the game:

```
Numbergame play = new Numbergame();
play.playgame();
```

Comment: now its working!! thank you! this was a great learning session as well